# Fit all elements within viewport on all platforms without scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

My aim is to fit all the contents of the page within viewport on all plaforms (mobile/desktop) screens.

The contents include `.main-carousel` which is an image slider. `.overlay` is the main overlay on the page

Here is a drawing of how the page should look.
[pagelayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX9PP.jpg)

Currently, there is a scroll bar that appears and the Purchase button on the page appears below the viewport. I'm using a 13" laptop here. How do I make it responsive on all browsers?
Here is a code snippet for your reference.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "50%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.left = "100%";
}
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.flickity-page-dots {
  display: none;
}

.main-carousel {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.carousel-cell img {
  max-width: 35%;
  /* full width */
  height: auto;
}

.carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  /* full width */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  /* center images in cells with flexbox */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flickity-enabled:focus .flickity-viewport {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
}

.flickity-button {
  background: transparent;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  width: 50%;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}


/*#text{
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}*/

.text-block {}

.text-block p {
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.button {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

#button {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#button a {
  background: #999;
  padding: 1em 2.4em;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#logo .logo-image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<htmL>

<head>

  <div id="logo">
    <div class="logo logo-image">
      <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b87a2662714e5f90127b5d6/t/5c01ecc388251b9d3ce78f00/1543630386191/?format=1500w" alt="Studio Otto Berlin">
    </div>
  </div>
</head>

<body>

  <span style="float:right;" onclick="openNav()">&#8641;open</span>
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <div class="text-block">
        <h1>"Fever" T-shirt</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
      <button class="button">Purchase</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left","contain": true,"wrapAround":true }'>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b87a2662714e5f90127b5d6/5beb5695032be4bf05089f8c/5beb8113cd83669970bfab29/1542161236370/studio-otto-rave-skateboards-editorial-003-compressor.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b87a2662714e5f90127b5d6/5beb5695032be4bf05089f8c/5beb8113cd83669970bfab29/1542161236370/studio-otto-rave-skateboards-editorial-003-compressor.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b87a2662714e5f90127b5d6/5beb5695032be4bf05089f8c/5beb8113cd83669970bfab29/1542161236370/studio-otto-rave-skateboards-editorial-003-compressor.jpg"></div>
    <div class="carousel-cell"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5b87a2662714e5f90127b5d6/5beb5695032be4bf05089f8c/5beb8113cd83669970bfab29/1542161236370/studio-otto-rave-skateboards-editorial-003-compressor.jpg"></div>

  </div>
  <div id="button"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>

</body>

</htmL>
```

When I resize the page using google developer tools, there is a lot of white space below the button. 
[White_space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LdSY.png)

How can I make the page responsive so that all the contents fit in the viewport? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look CSS documentation for **grid** layout. You can define application main layout using that. Individual widget areas you can then define using **flex** elements (display: flex). Another thing to get familiar with is **media query** that you can specifically tell how elements should behave on a different resolution. Oh and check also unit types **vh and vw** instead of using pixels. I hope these will get you ideas how to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Janne. I will look into those suggestions.